# XCode's #pragma - mark for Atom editor?

Tags: xcode, atom-editor

Is there a XCode's "pragma mark" for Atom editor?

It would be very great.

Thank you for helping.

Eric

Comment: I doubt it; `#pragma` is very specific to C-based languages and Atom is a general-purpose text editor.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know if there is a plug in who could enable a similar feature?

Answer (score 0):

This is the best package I could find so far: https://atom.io/packages/comment-anchors